# Cookies are not saved. Set cookie in views

Tags: django

```
def myview(request):
    item = Item.objects.all().count()
    if not request.COOKIES.get('mycookie', None):
        response.set_cookie('mycookie', item)
        n =  request.COOKIES.get('mycookie')
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'n': n}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It seems that my cookies are not saved. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a cookie, this is a request for the client (the browser) to store this information in its cookie storage.

Highly simplified, it works like this:

- You tell your code, set a cookie.
- Your code tells the browser, hey set this cookie.
- Browser says, okay its set.
- On the next request, browser will send the cookie back to you.

It will be available for reading on any requests **after** the request where you set it. So when you refresh the page, the cookie will be "readable" by your code.